# port 3306 mysql accessible from internet but closed for office network

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to access MySQL Database configured on a remote host but I'm unable to do so from my office network. I can however access it from any other network except the office network. Also, when I checked the port 3306, it shows that its Open when connected with external network but Closed when connected with the office network.

From office network:

```
nmap -p 3306 <hostname>
Host is up (0.0020s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql
```

From external network:

```
nmap -p 3306 <hostname>
Host is up (0.30s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp open mysql
```

The remote database is not managed by us so I want to make sure there is no problem at our network before going back to the other team managing the database.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your database server should be listening on a specific network interface which is different from the network interface connected to the office network. Can you check what are the interfaces by typing `ifconfig`?